# trace the path to the base url from which the external link has been crawled in nutch

Tags: cassandra, nutch

I have implemented a Nutch crawler with a depth 3. Now when I fetch data into cassandra I have a table with the URL and the data from that particular URL. So is there any way  I can trace back the path to the native URL from which this depth crawled URL has been updated in the seed.txt and crawled.

Answer (score 0):

So basically you want to know from which seed URL (in your `seed.txt` file) a particular URL is coming from? If this is the case then is basically easy, the `seed.txt` file supports adding a [custom metadata key/vale pair after the URL](https://wiki.apache.org/nutch/bin/nutch%20inject). Basically just use the following format:

```
URL <tab> key=value
```

for example something like:

```
http://my-news-site.com    source=news
```

After that you'll need to use and configure the `urlmeta` plugin to propagate that metadata into all the outlinks of the seed URL. This would cause that you end up with a `source` field in your index for the original seed URL and all its outlinks.

Comment: Would that help me with internal links as well as external links? Like if a particular URL has another URL linked to it from a different domain? @Jorge Luis

Comment: Yes @user7140275 this will propagate the metadata that you want (including that metadata specified in the `seed.txt` file) into EVERY outlink detected on the webpage. At the moment there is an open Jira ticket [NUTCH-1872](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-1872) about filtering to which outlinks the metadata is propagated